# There's a way to prioritize Servlet Filter execution?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Can (should) I prioritize filter execution in Java-Tomcat configuration? How and why (not)? For example, If I need to execute a DB-Connection filter before a Session-treatment filter, would I do it in filters' execution order or there's an issue in my application model? Thanks!

Comment: Put them in the right order in your `web.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter execution order is same as the order of filters you specify in your web.xml file. And I think there is no issue in doing so. But if you don't want to do so, you can do it in one filter. But I prefer seperaate filters for different purposes..